# Array Reading problems

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Good day . I've the following portions of code which i'm struggling to make work . i've a text file with questions and it is structured in the way that each question inside the text file occupy 10 lines but i want just to display the 6 first lines out of each question then hide the remaining .

my questions in the texfile look like :

```
Collections
Which of these is not an example of a "real-life" collection?
a. The cards you hold in a card game.
b. Your favorite songs stored in your computer.
c. The players on a soccer team.
d. The number of pages in a book. 

d. /// answer


Multithreading
Indefinite postponement is often referred to as __________.
a. deadlock.
b. indigestion.
c. starvation.
d. None of the above.

c. /// answer
```

basically it has just to display the questions but not the answer . that's what i want to achieve so far .

Any help will be appreciated .

```
File filing = new File(file);


        pattern.setFileName(filing.getAbsolutePath());

        if(filing.getAbsoluteFile().exists())
        {
            try{

            ReadFile myFile = new ReadFile(pattern.getFileName());

            String[ ] aryLines = myFile.OpenFile( );

             int i;


            for ( i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++ ) 
                {
                    System.out.println( aryLines[ i ] ) ;

                    if(i == 6)
                        i = i+3;
                }
```

ReadFile class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
public class ReadFile 
{
    private String path;

     ///////////// set file name

    public ReadFile(String filePath) 
    {
        path = filePath;
    }

    public String[] OpenFile() throws IOException
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);

        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);


        int numberOflines = path.length();

        String[] textData = new String[numberOflines];

        int count;

        for(count = 0; count < numberOflines; count++)
        {
            textData[count] = textReader.readLine();


        }

        textReader.close();
        return textData;
    }

    int readLines() throws IOException
    {
        FileReader fileToRead = new FileReader(path);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileToRead);

        String aLine;

        int numberOfLines = 0;

        while ( ( aLine = br.readLine( ) ) != null ) 
            {
                numberOfLines++;
            }

            br.close();

            return numberOfLines;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your file with questions, and complete code.

Comment: Also, you need to explicitly state where you are stuck. That is not given in the problem statement.

Comment: `i == 6` works only the first time. The next time you want to skip lines `i == 16` ...

Comment: my questions in the file looks like this Collections
Which of these is not an example of a "real-life" collection?
a. The cards you hold in a card game.
b. Your favorite songs stored in your computer.
c. The players on a soccer team.
d. The number of pages in a book. 

d.

Comment: The constructs used are definietly not part of the Java STL. There is no class called `ReadFile`. Please post the whole code in question. Also, please state exactly, what your problem is, e.g. which output you expect vs. which output you get.

Comment: Collections
Which statement is false?
a. A collection is an object that can hold references to other objects.
b. The collection interfaces declare the operations that can be performed on each type of collection.
c. Unfortunately, collections discourage software reuse because they are non-portable. 
d. Collections are carefully constructed for rapid execution and efficient use of memory.

c.

Comment: @Pshemo I think these are examples of the files OP is reading.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yes, I realised that after reading OPs first comment (I have bad habit of starting reading comments from most recent ones :/)

Comment: i've refined the questions

Comment: i just expect to see Collections
Which of these is not an example of a "real-life" collection?
a. The cards you hold in a card game.
b. Your favorite songs stored in your computer.
c. The players on a soccer team.
d. The number of pages in a book. 
 and then Multithreading
The main method executes in the ________ thread of execution.
a. starting
b. main
c. local
d. None of the above.   but the answer has to be hidden

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try and iterate in nested for loops like this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < aryLines.length; i += 10) {
        // every iteration brings you to the beginning of a new question
        for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            System.out.println(aryLines[i + j]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is really hard reading your unformatted comments. Maybe it would help if you can give us a snippet of the file you are reading. 
For example, I do not know, what this "Collections Collections" String is about and if it comes from a single line or from multiple lines. etc. pp

Comment: @mkwilfreid Don't post text in which line separators matters as comment because it removes them. Instead consider editing your question with more informations or link to something like http://pastebin.com/ which will contain your text example.

Comment: Collections
Collections
Which statement is false?
a. A List is an ordered Collection.
b. A List cannot contain duplicate elements. 
c. A List is sometimes called a sequence.
d. Lists are zero based.
Collections
Collections
Which of the following does not implement interface List?
a. ArrayList.
b. LinkedList. 
c. Vector.
d. ListIterator.


Multithreading
A new thread begins its life cycle by transitioning to the __________ state. 
a. runnable.
b. waiting.

Comment: thanks a lot it's worked, i was just printing the header at the top that's why

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually even need `ReadFile` class to read all lines from file. Java provides you `Files` utility class in `java.nio.file` package which has `readAllLines(Path)` method. Also `i==6` as mentioned already in comments will let you handle only sixth line, but it will not handle 16th, 26th. To handle these cases you can either create two loops, like in [gutenmorgenuhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26919092/1393766)

```
for (int questionNumber; ...)
   for (1..6 lines of each question)
       printLine
```

or just check if last digit is `6`. To get this last digit you can use modulo (reminder) operator `%` so you condition can be rewritten as `if ( i % 10 == 6)`.

So little simplified code which will handle problem from your question can look like

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"));
// or in Java 7
// List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(lines.get(i));
    if (i % 10 == 6)
        i = i + 3;// or +4 if you don't want to separate questions with empty line
}
```

Comment: your method is providing the following error error: method readAllLines in class Files cannot be applied to given types; because my textfile name is not provided but, rather input from the textfield. how do i get what is the textfiled and put it in List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get( fileField.getText()));

Comment: @mkwilfreid At start of code example from your question you are using `File filing = new File(file);`. I assume that `file` argument used in `new File(...)` constructor is String similar to the one from code example `"input.txt"`. If that is the case then you should be able to use it like `List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file));`.

Comment: that's how it is, i tried the method you showed, but couldn't made it work maybe i was missing something until i saw you posted it. String file = fileField.getText();  File filing = new File(file);

Comment: Could you paste exact error massage you are getting (it will need to be formatted so link to pastebin.com would be fine)?

Comment: that's the error " error: method readAllLines in class Files cannot be applied to given types; "

Comment: @mkwilfreid It should also say what types it expected and what type it got instead. That part is very important to solve this problem.

Comment: that's the full error :  
                                          ^
  required: Path,Charset
  found: Path
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Comment: @mkwilfreid OK, apparently `readAllLines(Path)` version of this method was added in Java 8 and you are most probably are using earlier version. In that case you will need to use `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"),Charset.defaultCharset());` or if you want to explicitly pass encoding of file you can use something like `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"),Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`.

Comment: You can also use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead of `Charset.forName("UTF-8")` like `Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("input.txt"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64903/discussion-between-mkwilfreid-and-pshemo).